# How to root the Samsung Galaxy 5

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-5

Anyone tried to root their Samsung Galaxy 5 (five) device? If so, what is the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You can root it with [Universal Androot](https://www.roidbay.com/apk/universal-androot/54).  Install it, run it, follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

No need for long procedures, download KingoRoot or any one-click root software on your PC and follow the instructions from there.. Just make sure you turn on developer option from your settings and use a usb cable that wont disconnect during the rooting process to avoid being bricked.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I did for my many devices

1. Download odin and samusng drivers for windows in your machine

2.get the twrp zip for your device from `https://twrp.me/Devices/`

3. From your phone turn on developer options by clicking build number which is in system info.
4. Turn on usb debugging and unlock oem in phone
5. Open odin in your windows, connect your phone in download/bootloader mode using `power button+ volume down key`(may differ)
6. in ap, select twrp image and select start 
   You successfully installed custom recovery in your phone. 
   it will automaticaaly reboot but don't do it since the stock rom will replace recovery so when it power off, remove the battery and on your phone in recovery mode using `power button + volume up` (may differ)
   next,
   you have to install the zip file of magisk from their official site `https://magiskmanager.com/`

Now you have succesfully rooted.
This is the best way to root and stable way since when we install custom recovery then we can easily install custom roms via the custom recovery.
Magisk will allow us to act as non root for google pay and games.
so this is very useful way to root

`For Lnux user`

If you are in linux

```
sudo apt install fastboot
```

2. Turn on usb debugging and unlock oem in phone
3. in terminal,

```
fastboot oem unlock
```

4. some steps will show in phone to confirm.. follow them
5. Download the twrp img file not zip file from the site
6. `fastboot flash recovery 'recovery.img'`

7.Below steps are  same as windows